# dart - returning a function value from a clause

Tags: dart

I'm trying to return a value, that a clause emits, as a function yield

I'll demonstrate:

```dart
someValue functionA() async {
  final functionClause func =
      (value) {
        // how to exit functionA with 'value'?
      }

  await functionB(
      functionClause: func
  );
}
```

As for the example above,`functionA` will return `func`'s `value`

Is there a possible way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are potentially looking for a [`Completer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html):

```dart
someValue functionA() async {
    final completer = Completer();

    final functionClause func =
        (value) {
            completer.complete(value);
        }

    await functionB(
        functionClause: func
        );

    return completer.future;
}
```

Note that with this setup `functionA` will only return the `value` from `func` once both `functionB` is done (as you are awaiting it) and `completer.complete` was called in `func`.

Answer (score 2):

You can plumb the return value through the various functions by making `func` return `value`, making `functionB` return the value of its supplied callback, and making `functionA` return the result of `functionB`:

```dart
Future<someValue> functionA() async {
  final functionClause func =
      (value) {
        ...
        return value;
      }

  return functionB(
      functionClause: func
  );
}
```

If you don't have control over `functionB` or if plumbing is too much work, you could have the nested `func` set a variable directly:

```dart
Future<someValue> functionA() async {
  someValue result;
  final functionClause func =
      (value) {
        ...
        result = value;
      }

  await functionB(
      functionClause: func
  );
  return result;
}
```

Also note that since `functionA` is declared as `async`, it must return a `Future`.